# Join multiple tables and pick results from most recent table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 4 tables. I want all the rows and cols from my first table tbl_2021 and only those data which are not in tbl_2021 but present in the the rest 3 tables, but based on one condition

- if there id exist in tbl_2020, tbl_2019 and in tbl_2018 then i need the id and it's details from the most recent table that is tbl_2020.
- if an id is across 2019 and 2018 table, then i need the data from 2019 so on like that.If in 2020 and 018 then 020 and so on
- if the same is across 2021,2020,2019 and 2018 then the data from 2021 is selected.

And -  I'm hail from a shell scripting background, and i've just started with sql. so if any noble mind could tell me the approach or what i should do to get these pieces together would mean more than happiness to me. Thank you

tbl_2021

| id | name | addr | location | country | contintent | gdp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | rob | dware | texas | us | us | 8 |
| 456 | lilly | gwood | london | uk | uk | 5 |
| 670 | rick | utown | newyrok | us | us | 8 |
| 490 | zang | kcity | hk | hongkong | hongkong | 6 |

tbl_020

| id | location | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 999 | ger | roger |
| 888 | bel | leslie |
| 670 | us | marie |

tbl_019

| id | location | name | data | network |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 999 | uk | roger | xx | na |
| 555 | rus | vladmir | ux | na |
| 879 | us | marie | xx | ua |
| 481 | cn | kim |  |  |

tbl_018

| id | location | name | data | network |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 823 | uk | roger | xx | na |
| 555 | rus | vladmir | ux | na |
| 879 | us | maria | xx | ua |
| 670 | us | marie | xy | uy |
| 888 | in | raj | xx | jo |

output:

| id | name | addr | location | country | contintent | gdp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | rob | dware | texas | us | us | 8 |
| 456 | lilly | gwood | london | uk | uk | 5 |
| 670 | rick | utown | newyrok | us | us | 8 |
| 490 | zang | kcity | hk | hongkong | hongkong | 6 |
| 999 | roger |  |  | ger |  |  |
| 888 | leslie |  |  | bel |  |  |
| 555 | vladmir |  |  | rus |  |  |
| 879 | marie |  |  |  | us |  |
| 481 | kim |  |  |  | cn |  |
| 823 | roger |  |  |  | uk |  |

Comment: Cryptic table names, cryptic column names, no defined relationships or keys, duplicated data - get someone with db design skills to help design your schema.

Comment: Sorry to say but your DB is nothing less than a mess. first create 4 temp tables and sort the data based on a date if available. After that do a full join with COALESCE inside the SELECT and a full outer join which could get you to your desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should fix your data model. It is not a good idea to store such data in separate *tables*.  Instead, you should store in a single table with a year column.

Second, I think you can solve your problem using `full join`, but it is a little tricky:

```
select coalesce(t21.id, t20.id, t19.id, t18.id) as id,
       coalesce(t21.name, t20.name, t19.name, t18.name) as name,
       t21.addr,
       . . . 
from tbl_2021 t21 full join
     tbl_2020 t20
     on t21.id = t20.id full join
     tbl_2019 t19
     on t19.id = coalesce(t21.id, t20.id) full join
     tbl_2018 t18
     on t18.id = coalesce(t21.id, t20.id, t19.id);
```

You need to carefully figure out how the columns should be pulled from the different tables.

Comment: Thanks for the quick turnaround. I never knew, that someone would even help! thank you so much. I have a question here, when you use COALESCE on Name, imagine if the tbl_21 got null name but a valid ID and tbl_20 got a no null name for the same ID. At that point, would this query go for the records in tbl_20 instead of tbl_21?

Comment: @lavanya_satheesh . . . No.  The columns are chosen in order based on the ordering in the `coalesce()`, the first non-`NULL` value on a column-by-column basis.

Answer (score 2):

First you can union all the data from four tables with union all. Then with row_number() we need to serialized rows for each id from higher to lower. Finally select one row for each id with highest year .

```
with cte as
(
select id,name  addr    ,location   ,country,   contintent,data,network, row_number()over (partition by  id order by sl ) rn from
    (
        select id,name  ,addr   ,location   , country,   contintent,data,network, 1 sl from tbl_21
        union all    
        select id,name  ,'' addr    ,location   ,'' country,''  contintent, data, network, 2 sl from tbl_20
        union all
        select id,name  ,'' addr    ,location   ,'' country,''  contintent, data,network, 3 sl from tbl_19
        union all
        select id,name  ,'' addr    ,location   ,'' country,''  contintent, data,network, 4 sl from tbl_18
    )t
)    
select id,name  ,addr   ,location   ,country,   contintent,data,network from cte where rn=1
```

Comment: Hi @Kazi. Thanks for your response. What does 'sl' stands for

Comment: It's just a column alias.  We need rows in descending order of years to select the row from table of highest year. Do, I have tagged each year with a serial number like 1 sl or 2 sl.

Comment: I have defined 1,2,3 and 4 as SL for year 21,20,19,18. So when I am ordering by SL in row_number() it's selecting rows from table of highest year first. So in outer query we are getting most recent data against each id by selecting rn=1.

Comment: @lavanya_satheesh hope your problem has been resolved.